# Singleton class return nil value for its NSString property

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, singleton, nsobject

I have a singleton class, and I have a property declared in it:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *currentTableName;
+ (SuperNoteManager*)sharedInstance;
```

**.m file**:

```
+ (SuperNoteManager*)sharedInstance
{
    static SuperNoteManager *_sharedInstance = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t oncePredicate;
    dispatch_once(&oncePredicate, ^{
        _sharedInstance = [[SuperNoteManager alloc] init];
    });
    return _sharedInstance;
}
```

When I run my app for the first time, there is no data in the data base,so it shows the `EmptyViewController`.

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) SuperNoteManager *myManager;


-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    _myManager=[SuperNoteManager sharedInstance];
}

-(void)changeRootView{

    UIStoryboard *storyboard=[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];

    HomeViewController *hVC=[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"HomeViewController"];

    UINavigationController *mNavVC=[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MainNavigationController"];

    mNavVC.viewControllers=@[hVC];

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow setRootViewController:mNavVC];

}

-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    if ( [_myManager checkForDataInAllTables]) {
        NSLog(@"All tables are empty");
    }else{
        //a note is saved, show home view controller
        if (![_myManager isDatabaseEmpty]) {
            [self changeRootView];
        }

    }

}
```

There is + button on `NavigationBar` on `EmptyNotesViewController`, and on tap '+', 
 `NotesViewController` is pushed from `EmptyNotesViewController`.
In the `NotesViewController`, after I write some notes, I save the notes in database:

`NotesViewController`:

```
@property (nonatomic,strong) SuperNoteManager *myManager; 

-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    _myManager.currentTableName=@"WorkTable";
}

-(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];

    if (self.isMovingFromParentViewController) {
        NSLog(@"going back");
        [self insertTextintoDatabase]; //Text is inserted . I double checked
    }

}
```

And then When I go back to my `EmpytNotesViewController`, I check for data, and if data is present, I change the `rootViewController` as it is not `EmptyNotesView` anymore.

So When I go back to my `EmptyNotesViewController`:

```
   -(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    if ( [_myManager checkForDataInAllTables]) {
        NSLog(@"All tables are empty");
    }else{
        //a note is saved, show home view controller

       //Put a breakpoint here
        if (![_myManager isDatabaseEmpty]) {
            [self changeRootView];
        }

    }

}
```

Here at the breakpoint `_myManager.currentTableName` is `nil`. **why?**
 I set it in the `NotesController`, and it became nil when it come back to the `EmptyNotesController`.

I thought once a value is set in singleton, it will persist as long as the app is closed/killed.

`Note`: I have declared the property of my Singleton class as strong and also all the properties in the singleton are declared as strong.

Answer (score 2):

It appears like you never get a reference to the `SuperNoteManager` singleton in `NotesViewController`, like you did in your `EmptyNotesController`.

**Therefore the `currentTableName` property never gets set in the first place.**

You want to insert:

```
_myManager = [SuperNoteManager sharedInstance];
```

in your `-viewDidAppear:` before you set the `currentTableName` property.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I did this in the view did load of the write notes . That's why I'm wondering y the property is nil when I go back and check in empty notes view

Comment: All other properties doesn't show nil, only this string property is getting nil

Comment: **well without posting all the code, it's difficult to tell what the problem is.** There doesn't appear to be anything wrong with what you've posted already, apart from what I've already said, but you make a few calls to methods which you haven't included. I suggest you create an empty project and add small amounts of code until your problem appears, or use breakpoints at every point you interact with the singleton to help isolate the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Will do that and get back to you.

Comment: Got the bug, I actually gave a nil string to the singleton class at one place I forgot to watch!!!

Comment: That would explain it! Glad you found the problem :)